# Object Variable - The local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have searched for the problem in everywhere. People told me that I did define the variable but not initialized it. However, if the variable was integer I could just assign it to the 0 at the beginning, but it's an Object variable. What to assign it?

[image: The error]

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Engine engine;
        MusicPlayer musicPlayer;
        Lights lights;
        LockDoors doors;
        
        
        System.out.println("FACADE PATTERN\n --------------------------");

        CarDriveFacade carDrive = new CarDriveFacade(engine, musicPlayer, lights, doors);
        carDrive.startCar();
        carDrive.stopCar();
    }

}
```

Facade Class:

```
public class CarDriveFacade {
    Engine engine;
    MusicPlayer musicPlayer;
    Lights lights;
    LockDoors doors;

    public CarDriveFacade(Engine engine, MusicPlayer musicPlayer, Lights lights, LockDoors doors){
        this.engine = engine;
        this.musicPlayer = musicPlayer;
        this.lights = lights;
        this.doors = doors;
    }
    public void startCar(){
        doors.close();
        engine.start();
        lights.on();
        musicPlayer.on();
    }

    public void stopCar(){
        musicPlayer.off();
        lights.off();
        engine.stop();
        doors.open();
        
    }
}
```

Subclass example:

```
public class LockDoors {
    LockDoors doors;

    LockDoors(LockDoors doors){
        this.doors=doors;
    }

    public void open(){
        System.out.println("Doors are open");
    }
    public void close(){
        System.out.println("Doors are closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make it `null`?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "LockDoors.close()" because "this.doors" is null

Comment: I meant to avoid an not initialized complaint by the compiler.  Obviously you need to assign an actual value to the variable before you can use it.

Comment: That is the question. What to assign Engine engine as an initial value it is not something like integer or String.

Comment: @KorayBarkin, maybe an Engine?!

Comment: @KorayBarkin You have obviously defined this, because it's your class. You should be the one defining it.

Comment: Look. I don't know what is so hard to understand. I'm keep saying that it is not an integer to define it as =0 or not a string to define as = "" as initial value. The compiler asks me to enter an initial value for Engine type of variable. How I'm suppose to enter initial value to that type of variable? Just write an example. It's simple.

Comment: Depending on the `Enginge` class it might be as simple as `Engine engine = new Engine();` (if the class has a constructor that takes no arguments). If the constructor needs arguments you have to provide them (similar to `new CarDriveFacade(engine, musicPlayer, lights, doors)`)

Comment: @KorayBarkin Or you could just initialize it with null, and then put a real value later.

Answer (score -1):

> Engine engine;

In this case "engine" is not an object,
It is just an Object Reference with a null value.

**You have to create an Object and assign it to the Object Reference at least before using its methods. Because {null}.method() is not a valid call.**

Comment: _You do not even need to assign a primitive datatype a value_ this is only true for fields, not for local variables. And the error message that the OP get's is about variables.

Comment: @ThomasKläger you are right about the local variables. I will alter my comment.